# Looking for solution to Cloudflare cache loading/serving issue. TYIA

Tags: wordpress, caching, cloudflare

the website becomes corrupt randomly serving Cloudflare cache.

[The issue at hand with inspect showing 404s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ita09.png)

This is an intermittent problem at which I'm trying to understand and resolve. I'll assume it's caused by Cloudflare and not the WordPress instance and or DO hosting as it's resolved when I purge Cloudflare cache.

Can anyone guide me to a solution or even closer to one?